# async Task<bool> method call in if condition

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, asynchronous, async-await

I would like to know if the following code will wait for the async method to complete before executing the main thread or will just continue the main thread if condition and consider the method return as false.

```
public async Task<bool> SomeMethod
{
    if(await AsyncMethod(param))
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

...

And the async method is defined as:

```
public async Task<bool> AsyncMethod(SomeClass param)
{
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: You have an `await` keyword there, so it should wait for the function to return, why would you think it wouldn't?

Comment: @CodingGorilla Well, it doesn't.  It will return immediatley upon hitting an `await`.  That's the *point* of `await`, it's asynchronous, and not a synchronous wait.

Comment: @Servy But it should not continue to execute the rest of the `SomeMethod` until it has received the result of `AsyncMethod`.  In other words, whenever `SomeMethod` is scheduled, it should not proceed into or past the `if` unless it has received the result of the call to `AsyncMethod`.

Comment: @CodingGorilla That's correct, and *radically* different from what you said the first time.

Comment: @Servy Ok, granted, I worded that question poorly.

Comment: It was just a code block not getting hit that made me think it could run the main thread along. But yes I read the msdn again and await should wait. Thanks for quick responses.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I would like to know if the following code will wait for the async method to complete before executing the main thread or will just continue the main thread if condition and consider the method return as false.

Neither.

`await` is an "asynchronous wait". In other words, the *method* will wait, but the *thread* will not.

When your method hits that `await` (assuming it actually has some waiting to do), it will immediately return an incomplete task to the caller of `SomeMethod`. The thread continues with whatever it wants to do. Later on, when the task being awaited completes, then `SomeMethod` will resume executing. When `SomeMethod` completes, the task it returned earlier will be completed.

I go into more detail on my [blog post on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Answer (score 6):

It will wait for the operation to complete.

Note how you're invoking the operation:

```
if(await AsyncMethod(param))
```

Two things:

1. Using the `await` keyword will, unsurprisingly, wait for the operation to complete.
2. If it *didn't* wait for the operation to complete then this would be a compiler error.  Because while a `bool` can be used in a conditional, a `Task<bool>` can not.

Answer (score 1):

`await`ing an `async` method will cause the calling thread to return from the method caller until the async method completes. Once the method completes, the calling thread (in a synchronized context) will switch back to where it left off. Without a synchronization context, the await method will still return back to the caller and execution of the calling method will resume (but not necessarily on the same thread it was originally called from).
This will happen regardless of the return type/value.

In your case (assuming the syntax is correct). `SomeMethod` (you need to add ()) will call `AsyncMethod` and return immediately. Once `AsyncMethod` is done, `SomeMethod` will switch back to where it left off, which is evaluating the returned value (`true` or `false`). If the value is true it will call //Do something, otherwise it will skip the if statement and finish executing `SomeMethod`.

Here is an example of where there is no synchronization context. Notice the thread id changes after "await getStringTask", and the rest of GetValue is executed on the "new" thread.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetValue();
        Console.WriteLine("test1");
        Console.WriteLine("1 " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async void GetValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(await AccessTheWebAsync());
        Console.WriteLine("2 " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("test2");
        Console.WriteLine("3 " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    private static async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
        Console.WriteLine("4 " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        string urlContents = await getStringTask;
        Console.WriteLine("5 " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return urlContents.Length;
    }
```

Prints

```
4 9
test1
1 9
5 13
47984
2 13
test2
3 13
```

Comment: `Once the method completes, the calling thread will switch back to where it left off.` This *can* happen, as a result of synchronization context, but it doesn't *necessarily* happen.  It's not inherent to `await` that this happens.  `SomeMethod will call AsyncMethod on a ThreadPool` There's no code shown to indicate this.  `AsyncMethod` is asynchronous, but that doesn't mean a thread pool thread is necessarily involved at all.

Comment: In my experience, once an awaited method completes, the calling thread context switches back to where it left off. Care to explain a case where it will not?

Comment: If your only experience is using `await` in a UI context where there is a synchronization context, then yes, that's what you'd see, because that's what happens *in that situation*, but that won't *always* be the case.  There won't be a synchronization context in all situations. As far as the thread pool is concerned, there are lots of ways to create asynchrony, using a separate thread is just one.  The other extremely common action would be IO.

Comment: I understand it may not be executed on a separate thread, and I edited my answer for correctness. You said it doesn't necessarily return back to where it left off. I am wondering in what case this will happen (aside from the program ending before it can finish)?

Comment: The `async` method will always return to its caller as soon as it has resolved the awaitable object to its value, that's not the statement of yours I quoted and commented on.  It's the statement that the calling thread is handling the continuation that is sometimes true, but not necessarily true.

Comment: Thanks @Servy, I updated my answer for correctness and added an example of how it will behave in a non-synchronized context.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it synchronous like this :

```
if(AsyncMethod(param).Result)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Hope it help ;)